# Sbt run command warning UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES

Tags: java, scala, maven, warnings

I want to execute a scala program cloned from github.. So, when I runned command line 'sbt run' in my work directory to run a scala program, It doesn't work and give me this warning:

```
>[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-stream_2.11/2.4.14/akka-stream_2.11-2.4.14.jar ...
>[info]     [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.akka#akka-stream_2.11;2.4.14!akka-stream_2.11.jar (64108ms)


>[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

>[warn]     ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

>[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

>[warn]     :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found

>[warn]     :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-contrib_2.11;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found

>[warn]     :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-testkit_2.11;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found

>[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

>[warn]     Note: Unresolved dependencies path:

>[warn]         com.typesafe.akka:akka-contrib_2.11:2.4-SNAPSHOT (/Users/USERNAME/.sbt/0.13/staging/37c68d5979975b2c113c/actoverse-scala/build.sbt#L7-15)
>[warn]           +- actoverse-for-akka:actoverse-for-akka_2.11:1.0

>[warn]         com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.11:2.4-SNAPSHOT (/Users/USERNAME/.sbt/0.13/staging/37c68d5979975b2c113c/actoverse-scala/build.sbt#L7-15)
>[warn]           +- actoverse-for-akka:actoverse-for-akka_2.11:1.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found

>unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-contrib_2.11;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found

>unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-testkit_2.11;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

What that means? I have search the problem but i'm not found nothing

Comment: Can you say which github project?

Comment: Of course, its name's Actoverse. https://github.com/45deg/Actoverse
I'm followed the readme but it brougth me here.

Answer (score 0):

This means that maven does not find the specified 2.4-SNAPSHOT versions of akka-aktor_2.11, akka-contrib_2.11 and akka-testkit_2.11 on maven central. If everything works as expected, don't worry, that's what "warning" is trying to tell you. If you do have problems, look for those Versions elsewhere or use a Version that's not a snapshot - you will have a higher probability everything is there if it's actually a release.

Comment: Thank you, No, it doesn't work. Could you or anyone give me a link of a user friendly guide of this dark world about snapshot mode of Akka toolkit?

Comment: That is nothing special about Akka, just that in your pom.xml, you have defined some dependencies on SNAPSHOT artifacts. What that exactly means, you can look up at google, basically it's not a release version. But for your problem, it doesn't really matter. What matters is that these Snapshots are not on maven central (you can go to maven.org and search for the artifacts). You need to change pom.xml to use a version that exists, for example 2.4.20 or 2.5.8

Comment: @f_s ok I found the github project. In build.sbt change all 2.4-SNAPSHOT to 2.4.20, and try if that works.

Comment: not yet.. 
the file build.sbt now is :
>name := "Actoverse Demo"
>version := "1.0"
>scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
>// scalaVersion := "2.12.4"is my version scala
>libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  >"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.20-SNAPSHOT" >changing()
>)
>resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at >"http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"
>lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(actoversePlugin)
>lazy val actoversePlugin = >RootProject(uri("https://github.com/45deg/Actoverse-Scala.git"))'
What's i wrong? i continue to run 'sbt run' but no effect appears

Comment: change 2.4.20-SNAPSHOT to just 2.4.20

Comment: Yes i tried it but nothing. I saw the dependence at http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/ and so i decided to try with 2.10 , 2.12 and 2.11. But nothing, is like if I never change my file, maybe i wrong in compilation ?

Comment: what happens if you delete the line that adds Akka Snapshot repository as resolver? Also, before you do sbt run, try running sbt reload and sbt clean compile, maybe sbt isn't using the changed file at all?

Comment: I have the same error, nothing is changed.. I also check the dependences unresolved in google and I saw that they work. They exist ! So the problem is not there but it doesn't work